# Terminal command to send data (plain text string) to a port at a remote computer

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, netcat

I am trying to send data (plain text string) to a port at a remote computer using terminal utility. The string would be used to trigger something on the remote computer running a program that would listen to that specific port.

I used netcat command and tried a few combination of the following but can't seem to get the parameter right. Can someone point me out where am I doing wrong?

```
eddy-2:Desktop eddy$ nc IPADDRESS PORT >  woc.txt
eddy-2:Desktop eddy$ nc IPADDRESS PORT <  woc.txt
```

P.S: woc.txt contains plain text string of the said command.

Edit: I am trying to send a string from OSX to Windows XP where the specific port is open by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use netcat as so:

Server: `cat woc.txt | nc -l -p PORT`

Client: `nc HOST PORT > woc.txt`

---

Thanks to garyjohn for the above modification.

Comment: Added an edit to my post above. I am trying to send a string from OSX to Windows XP where the specific port is open by default. Must cat and netcat be running at the same time for this thing to work.

Note: I tried quite a number of other combination from man page but felt that I was missing something so I asked.

Comment: @Eddy - No. Run the **server first** (it will appear to hang while waiting for a client), **client second**.

Comment: `nc IPADDRESS PORT < woc.txt` should work fine. What do have listening on the server's PORT?

Comment: @Eddy: Your server command is missing a `-p`. It should be `nc -l -p PORT < woc.txt`. Also, I understood new123456 to want to send the contents of woc.txt _to_ the server.

Comment: @garyjohn - Correct. Quoting Eddy: **woc.txt contains plaintext string of the said command**